# Xcode Get Object from Top Level Object

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

In my iOS app setup, I have a universal object (lets call it `UniversalObj`) declared in the top level object. (`SampleAppDelegate` in my case)

Within this, I have a UITabBarController containing two `UIViewController` (which I want to have access to `UniversalObj`.

In `SampleAppDelegate`, I have tried the following to pass `UniversalObj` to it:

```
MyViewController *vc = (MyViewController *) [self.tabBarController.viewControllers.objectAtIndex:0];
[vc setMyObj:self.universalObject];
```

The problem with this is that when I do this, sometimes, the view hasn't loaded yet so `MyViewController.myObj==null`.

Now, I am trying to access `SampleAppDelegate` (of type `NSObject`) from `MyViewController`. I can get to the `UITabBarController` using: `***self.parentViewController***`, but I don't know how to get to `SampleAppDelegate`.

How can I access `UniversalObj` in `SampleAppDelegate` from `MyViewController`? How can I change the `self.parentViewController` line in `MyViewController` to get to `SampleAppDelegate`? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Guvvy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was able to access the object from `MyViewController` like this:

```
[self setMyObj:[(SampleAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate universalObj]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use `-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]`:

```
NSArray * topLevelObjects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:pwner options:options];
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get a UINib object? Do I just make one using `[UINib alloc]`? And what should I specify for the `owner` parameter? Is it just `self.parentViewController`?

Comment: @Guvvy a+b) `+[UINib nibWithNibName:bundle:]` is the common way. c) You'll have to determine that based on the actual nib you are loading here -- what is its File Owner? Does that correspond to an existing object/instance or a new instance?

Comment: I figured it out using another way, but thanks for your help!